# How to specialise template method with type that itself is a template where only the return type relies on the template type?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to specialise a single template method in a non-template class to use an `std::vector` however only the return type of the method uses the template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T Get()
    {
        std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
};

template<>
int Foo::Get()
{
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    return 12;
}

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> Foo::Get()
{
    std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
    return std::vector<T>();
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto s = foo.Get<std::string>();
    auto i = foo.Get<int>();
}
```

This compiles with an error indicating that the `std::vector` attempted specialisation does not match any prototype of `Foo`, which is completely understandable.

In case it matters, use of C++14 is fine and dandy.

Comment: Like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1af61a9d5725a51) ? I don't get what syntax you expect.

Comment: You cannot partially specialize functions in C++ - so `template<T> std::vector<T>` is not allowed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only partially specialize classes (structs) ([cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization)) - so the way to overcome your problems is to add helper struct to allow this partial specialization of `std::vector<T>` - e.g. this way:

```
class Foo
{
private: // might be also protected or public, depending on your design
    template<typename T>
    struct GetImpl
    {
        T operator()()
        {
            std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
            return T();
        }
    };
public:
    template<typename T>
    auto Get()
    {
        return GetImpl<T>{}();
    }
};
```

For `int`  - you can fully specialize this function:

```
template<>
int Foo::GetImpl<int>::operator()()
{
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    return 12;
}
```

For `std::vector<T>` you have to specialize entire struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct Foo::GetImpl<std::vector<T>>
{
    std::vector<T> operator()()
    {
        std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
        return std::vector<T>();
    }
};
```

Comment: nitpick: GetImpl should be private

Comment: @Caleth - sure it can, and in general case it should be private.

Answer (score 3):

[Partial specialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization) of `template` functions (including member functions) is not allowed. One option is to overload instead using [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae). For example,

```
/// auxiliary for is_std_vetor<> below
struct convertible_from_std::vector
{
    template<typename T> 
    convertible_from_std::vector(std::vector<T> const&); 
};

template<typename V>
using is_std_vector
    = std::is_convertible<V,convertible_from_std_vector>;

class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t< is_std::vector<T>::value,T>
    Get()
    {
        std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
    template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_std::vector<T>::value,T>
    Get()
    {
        std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
        return T();
    }
};
```

Note that the helper class `is_std_vector` may be useful in other contexts as well, so it worth having somewhere. Note further that you can make this helper class more versatile by asking for any `std::vector` or specific `std::vector<specific_type, specific_allocator>`. For example,

```
namespace traits {
    struct Anytype {};
    namespace details {
        /// a class that is convertible form C<T,T>
        /// if either T==AnyType, any type is possible
        template<template<typename,typename> C, typename T1=Anytype,
                                                typename T2=Anytype>
        struct convCtTT
        {
            convCtTT(C<T1,T2> const&);
        };

        template<template<typename,typename> C, typename T1=Anytype>
        struct convCtTT<C,T1,AnyType>
        {
            template<typename T2>
            convCtTT(C<T1,T2> const&);
        };

        template<template<typename,typename> C, typename T2=Anytype>
        struct convCtTT<C,AnyType,T2>
        {
            template<typename T1>
            convCtTT(C<T1,T2> const&);
        };

        template<template<typename,typename> C>
        struct convCtTT<C,AnyType,AnyType>
        {
            template<typename T1, typename T2>
            convCtTT(C<T1,T2> const&);
        };
    }
    template<typename Vector, typename ValueType=AnyType,
                              typename Allocator=AnyType>
    using is_std_vector
      = std::is_convertible<Vector,details::convCtTT<std::vector,ValueType,
                                                                 Allocator>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't partially specialze template in c++. You need to overload your function and pass the type in parameters.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    T Get()
    {
       return  this->getTemplate(static_cast<T*>(0)); // 
    }
private:
    template<class T> T getTemplate(T* t)
    {
         std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
         return T();
    }
    template<class T> std::vector<T> getTemplate(std::vector<T>* t)
    {
         std::cout << "vector" << std::endl;
         return std::vector<T>();
    }
};

template <> int Foo::getTemplate(int* t)
{
    std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
    return 12;
}
int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    auto s = foo.Get<std::string>();
    auto i = foo.Get<int>();
    auto v = foo.Get<std::vector<int>>();
}
```

Edit : fixed a typo in the code

Comment: Real tag as proposed by @PiotrSkotnicki seems cleaner and handles more types (as reference).

Comment: About handling more type, both method handle all T and std::vector<T> while allowing specific type specialization.

Could you elaborate on why it seems cleaner ?

Comment: You don't handle `int&`, and pointers are regular types (which can be deferenced for example). `tag<T>` is dedicated.